# Resonating structures of (pentan‐2‐ylidene)oxidanium

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance, hydrocarbons

> Draw resonating strictures of the following compound:
>
> [image: (pentan‐2‐ylidene)oxidanium]

In this molecule there are two π-components, but they are not conjugated.
According to me, as there is no conjugation, it should not have a resonating structure.

But it has. Why?

Comment: @SoumikDas It does have two mesomeric structures not tautomers. In case of cations structures with broken bonds are important contributors.

Comment: Resonance is not limited to pi systems; you probably have heard of hyperconjugation, too. The structure has at least two more significant contributing structures. Draw the structures placing the charge at the adjacent atoms. || I personally do not agree with the close votes on this question; I find it clear enough, providing enough context of the thought process, and not trivial.